# how to find a key and return its path through the hierarchy in a JSON using perl

Tags: json, perl

```
{

  "root1" : {
      "sub1" : null,
      "sub2" : {
         "subsub1" : {
            "key1" : {

            },
            "key2" : {

            },
            "key3" : {

            },
            "key4" : {

            }
         }
      },
      "sub3" : {
         "subsub2" : {
            "key5" : {

            }
         }
      }
  },
  "root2" : {
      "sub1" : null,
      "sub2" : {
         "subsub1" : {
            "key1" : {

            },
            "key2" : {

            },
            "key3" : {

            },
            "key4" : {

            }
         }
      },
      "sub3" : {
         "subsub2" : {
            "key8" : {

            }
         }
      }
  }
}
```

consider the above json.
How to know if 'key8' exists in this json and also find the path where its found in the json.

e.g if searched for 'key8' need to get output similar to :

```
root2->sub3->subsub2->key8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a straightforward tree traversal. The following returns as soon as a match is found (rather than looking for all matches).

```
sub key_search {
    my $target = $_[1];   
    my @todo = [ $_[0] ];
    while (@todo) {
        my ($val, @path) = @{ shift(@todo) };
        my $reftype = ref($val);
        if (!$reftype) {
           # Nothing to do
        }
        elsif ($reftype eq 'HASH') {
           for my $key (keys(%$val)) {
              return @path, $target if $key eq $target;

              push @todo, [ $val->{$key}, @path, $key ];
           }
        }
        elsif ($reftype eq 'ARRAY') {
           for my $i (0..$#$val) {
              push @todo, [ $val->[$i], @path, $i ];
           }
        }
        else {
           die("Invalid data.\n");
        }
    }

    return;
}

my @path = key_search($data, 'key8')
   or die("Not found.\n");
```

Notes

- The result is ambiguous if the data can contain arrays, and if any of the hashes can have integers for keys. Steps can be taken to disambiguate them.
- The above doesn't check for cycles, but those can't exist in JSON.
- Replace `push` with `unshift` to get a depth-first search instead of a breadth-first search.

Comment: Decoded of course. Your question has nothing to do with JSON